# BigQuery Dataset/Table expiration by Policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-bigquery

I'm trying to figure out if I can create multiple service accounts and for each service account create a different Policy (or even a generic policy).
In this policy I want to set the default retention for a dataset/table.
Only I (admin) can change the retention after table creation.

This is very important to control costs.

Did anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Cloud Platform (GCP) it is possible to [create different service accounts with distinct roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating). These roles give access to specific resources across different services. In addition to the [already existing roles in Bigquery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control), GCP allows to set service accounts with [customized roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-custom-roles).

To control costs, the Project Admin or BigQuery Admin can establish a particular [expiration date for a dataset](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets) and [grant access to other service accounts with restricted permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-access-controls) like BigQuery Job User or BigQuery Data Viewer, for example. This way, all the tables included in the dataset will have a default expiration date (set by the administrator) that all the other service accounts could not modify.

Comment: tnx for the detailed explanation. what if a service account creates a new table in a new dataset? or a new table where they set an expiration date?

Comment: Consider the following situation: the Admin (or other service account with the [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#required_permissions)) generates a dataset “dataset_1” and sets the expiration date in 7 days. This means that any given table created without an expiration date inside this dataset will be automatically deleted in a week. Notice that this only applies to the “dataset_1”. The other datasets may not even have an expiration date at all, so tables included in different ones like, for example, “dataset_2” are not affected by the aforementioned date rule.

Comment: In the case that expiration dates are set in individual tables, [the expiration date defined for the entire dataset will be ignored](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time). Therefore, there is no mechanism to prevent a user from creating tables without allowing them to set an expiration date. Also, when working with BigQuery, it is useful to follow [these practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-storage) in order to reduce unnecessary costs.